# Maven : Failed to execute Avro goal (Error compiling protocol file)

Tags: java, maven, avro

I have some Avro files using custom Logical Types. When I try to build my project using mvn clean install in order to generate automatically my Java classes. I've tried the following example of the implementation of Street type (https://github.com/markush81/avro-examples). I get the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.0:schema (schemas) on project atlas_v: Error compiling protocol file to project\src\main\java
```

Here is my `pom.xml` below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vadis</groupId>
    <artifactId>atlas_v</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <atlas.version>2.0.0</atlas.version>
        <avro.version>1.11.0</avro.version>
        <spark.version>3.0.1</spark.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-atlas</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-atlas</id>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        .......
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.atlas</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlas-common</artifactId>
            <version>${atlas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.atlas</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlas-client-v2</artifactId>
            <version>${atlas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.atlas</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlas-client-v1</artifactId>
            <version>${atlas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
     .... dependencies
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            .... others plugins
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schemas</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                    <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                    <customConversions>
                        <customConversion>com.vadis.atlas_v.model.avro.utils.StreetConversion</customConversion>
                    </customConversions>
                    <customLogicalTypeFactories>                       
 
<customLogicalTypeFactory>com.vadis.atlas_v.model.avro.utils.StreetLogicalTypeFactory</customLogicalTypeFactory>
                    </customLogicalTypeFactories>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error. My issue was that the `.java` source files that Avro was compiling to already existed and were owned by another user.